# Xperia XZ recording video sync problems

Tags: sony-xperia, video-recording

I have an Xperia XZ F8331 with Android 8.0.0, which has been working fine for months. Recently, however, whenever I record a video it works for a few seconds, then the picture will freeze for a short time but continue recording sound, then everything will restart, meaning the recorded video is way out of sync with the sound for the rest of the video.

It's basically made it unusable for recording videos.

Nothing has changed; it is recording to the flash card, but it is a high speed card and has always worked fine before.

What could the cause be?

Comment: you may want to consider re-flashing your ROM/Firmware. This always works with my friend. You have the same phone unit.